# Query error not getting numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prestashop

Here is my query, I am trying to get numbers from another table using a number from another table here is my query ...

```
$order_id = $template_vars['{order_name}'];
            // Query to find the product id for the current order and then set it to a variable
            $query="SELECT product_id FROM ps_order_detail WHERE id_order = $order_id";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $Product_id = $row['0'];
            // get all the custom part numbers and set them to the variables
            $customnumbers ="SELECT API, SWAIM, JOHN_CRANE, SNOW_WELL, MIDAS, QUINN, WILSON, WEATHERFORD, HF, BLACK_GOLD, EDI, SO_CAL_PUMPS, WEST_RIVER
                                FROM ps_product_part_number WHERE Product_ID = $Product_id";
            $secondresult = mysql_query($customnumbers);
            $secondrow = mysql_fetch_row($secondresult);
            $API = $secondrow['0'];
            $SWAIM = $secondrow['1'];
            $JOHN_CRANE = $secondrow['2'];
            $SNOW_WELL = $secondrow['3'];
            $MIDAS = $secondrow['4'];
            $QUINN = $secondrow['5'];
            $WILSON = $secondrow['6'];
            $WEATHERFORD = $secondrow['7'];
            $HF = $secondrow['8'];
            $BLACK_GOLD = $secondrow['9'];
            $EDI = $secondrow['10'];
            $SO_CAL_PUMPS = $secondrow['11'];
            $WEST_RIVER = $secondrow['12'];
```

Comment: what is the error? and should `$template_vars['{order_name}']` be `$template_vars['{$order_name}']`?

Comment: this is in prestashop and im trying to get the partnumber to show on the email

Comment: This looks like a poorly designed table!

Answer (score 3):

How about doing it in one step with a join?

```
SELECT ppn.*
FROM ps_product_part_number ppn
join ps_order_detail od on od.product_id = ppn.Product_ID
WHERE od.id_order = $order_id
```